# Update route53 domain registrant contact information via aws cli

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-route53

Hopefully someone out there can help me because I can't seem to find the answer in any of the documentation or code. I'm attempting to standardize the domain contact info for our domains registered in route53 after my company's recent name change. I can programmatically change the admin and tech contact information easily enough using `aws route53domains update-domain-contact --domain-name <DOMAIN> --admin-contact <CONTACT INFO> --tech-contact <CONTACT INFO>`.

If I attempt to change the `--registrant-contact` (our company name is in the first name of the contact, so that is included in what's being changed), I get back an error stating `An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the UpdateDomainContact operation: Changing owner's first or last name is a change of ownership.`. I can't seem to figure out how to allow ownership contact changes via the aws-cli. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this doc help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-update-contacts.html

Comment: Unfortunately no. Our TLD is a .com, so it doesn't require special handling. I am changing the owner, as the contact type is "COMPANY" and we're changing the organization as well as the first and last names, but thats what's throwing the error above. I can do the change just fine in the AWS console, but I've yet to find a way to get it to successfully update in the aws-cli.

Comment: You will need to transfer ownership. That means registering the name again via a transfer. I do not recommend that as that resets the clock on the age of your domain. However, company policy might require you to do that. IIRC you cannot transfer a domain within the same AWS account, you would need to transfer to a different account.